# How can I deal with big numbers with big magnitude?

Tags: optimization, computer-arithmetic

I'm trying to solve optimization problem with very big numbers with large magnitude: from $10^3$ up to $10^9$. I'm using LBFGS-b fortran solver, but almost always I get `ABNORMAL` errors or invalid result. I think it happens due to numbers amplitude and size.

What approaches can be used to deal with it?

Comment: I only heard of "amplitude" in physics. Please explain more detailed what it is in this context.

Comment: As the authors wrote in their [1994 paper](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~inavon/5420a/lbfgsb.pdf): "This type of failure will usually occur only if the user has specified high accuracy in the solution and L-BFGS is having difficulties meeting this accuracy."

Comment: @Peter I think "magnitude" would be a better term. I mean the input numbers have wildly different exponents. For example, there are numbers $10^3$, and there are numbers $10^8$, and because of this, numeric issues may arise during the work of the solver.

Comment: Logarithms were made for the exact reason of dealing with large numbers. I'm not sure, but maybe using logarithms will help?

Comment: Where do these big numbers appear in the problem?